# how to check what the value of Parameter in Oracle PLSQL Procedure

Tags: oracle

I am in need of amending a procedure to include new data in which a parameter has been set. I need to check the value of the parameter so that I can test my code individually before it is implemented. below is portion of code which has parameter.

```
PROCEDURE Get_All_MT (i IN NUMBER)
AS
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO mrr_reten_mt_obp_cli (
     AMI_SCHEMA,
     UAN,
     PRODUCT_CLASS,
     POL_NO
   )
      SELECT a.ami_schema,
             a.uan,
             a.product_class,
             a.pol_no
        FROM mrr_retention_c_cover_item a,
             att_axa_uan agt,
             amt_structure str
       WHERE a.accident_date BETWEEN TRUNC (ADD_MONTHS (SYSDATE, i - 1), 'MONTH')
                                 AND TRUNC (ADD_MONTHS (SYSDATE, i), 'MONTH')
                                     - (1 / (60 * 60 * 24))
```

As you can see parameter "I" is been used in for accident_date range. I need to know what is the value of I so that it can be replaced while the code is been executed individually.

Answer (score 2):

Log the value using [`DBMS_OUTPUT`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TTPLP/d_output.htm#TTPLP036):

```
PROCEDURE Get_All_MT (i IN NUMBER)
AS
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( i );
  INSERT INTO ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I would `create table log_params (param varchar2(30), value varchar2(200), log_time date);` and procedure:

```
create or replace procedure log_param(param varchar2(30), value varchar2(200)) as
pragma autonomous transaction
begin
insert into log_params values (param, value, sysdate);
commit;
end;
/
```

And include in your code: `log_param('i', i);`. Then examinate results in table `log_params`

Comment: Correct solution, but maybe a bit overkill.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I've posted that as a solution because dbms_output is not always feasible. It is obvious it is faster to use `dbms_output` but when you want to gather those params for some period of calling procedure it is much easier to log and then analyse.